# How can I reflect the type of a collection in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm trying to reflect on the parameterized type of a collection, for example:

```
val model = List(1)
val classSymbol = currentMirror.classSymbol(model.getClass )
val typeParamArgs = classSymbol.typeParams
println(typeParamArgs)
```

Unfortunately this only gives me 'B' as the type, not Int as I'd hoped.  How can I reflect to know that this is a List[Int]?  Can I get this statically (preferred)?

Comment: Unless scala reflection does something special, you can't do this because the type literally doesn't exist at runtime. Statically you can get the type by e.g. `typeOf`, or more usually by having your generic method require a context bound of `TypeTag`, viz: `def myMethod[T: TypeTag](t: T) = ...`.

Comment: Yeah, and `typeOf[T]` requires an implicit instance (or view) of `TypeTag[T]` to compile.